# Catch button click on user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window with a button and usercontrol. Now when I click on the button, the raised event, I wanna catch on usercontrol. I guess this principle it called event tunneling. But I don't know too, if this way would be the right way to catch the button click event.

Example

```
<Window x:Class="EventTunneling.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:EventTunneling"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions> 

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Click me"></Button>
        <uc:Control Grid.Row="1"></uc:Control>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="EventTunneling.Control"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now i want to catch the event on the partial class of usercontrol, that was raised from main window. How can i do that?

```
namespace EventTunneling
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Control.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Control : UserControl
    {
        public Control()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a datagrid on the usercontrol and an object collection as datacontext to this datagrid. On the main window i have a save button. When i click on the save button, then i want to save the object collection an datagrid as xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're doing this *all* wrong. First, you need to data bind your collection from the code behind to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property. Then, when the `Button` is clicked, just handle it in the code behind, where you have access to the collection and simply save it however you like:

In `UserControl`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />
```

In `MainWindow`:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" />
```

In code behind (you should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on this property):

```
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> Items { get; set; }
```

...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveAsXml(Items);
}
```

In code behind constructor (or set it in any valid way you prefer):

```
DataContext = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a public event on the window.
2. Fire the event when the button is clicked.
3. Subscribe to the event from your control

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this when the button is clicked make a call to a public method in your user Control :

```
namespace EventTunneling
{
    public partial class Control : UserControl
    {
      public Control()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      public void CatchEventOnUserControl()
      {
          //do your job here
          //....
      }
    }
}
```

then when the button is clicked call the CatchEventOnUserControl method

```
<Window x:Class="EventTunneling.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:EventTunneling"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions> 

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <uc:Control x:Name="mycontrol" Grid.Row="1"></uc:Control>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind is

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mycontrol.CatchEventOnUserControl();
    }
}
```